# Vim templates, get filename and use it

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I am writing a rudimentary Vim template for Java files that creates a bare skeleton class when I create a new file with the .java extension.

Example:

```
vim Banana.java
```

Vim creates a file including code like this:

```
public class TODO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ...
```

My objective is to change my default class name, `TODO`, to the name of the file without the extension so that:

```
vim Coconut.java
```

creates:

```
public class Coconut {
```

rather than:

```
public class TODO {
```

How can I achieve that, please? I have searched the site and there are scripts that extract the name in a variable and perform :substitute in the right place, but I don't know how to locate the right place and position the filename there.

I read my template files by extension from my .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile * silent! 0r $HOME/vimfiles/templates/%:e.vim_template
```

or:

```
autocmd BufNewFile * silent! 0r $HOME/.vim/templates/%:e.vim_template
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this might help? http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_filename

With this you can get the current filename:

```
expand("%:t:r")
```

Specifically, you are probably looking for this:

```
%s/TODO/\=expand("%:t:r")/g
```

A full example:

```
function! NewFile()
    silent! 0r $HOME/vimfiles/templates/%:e.vim_template
    s/FILENAME/\=expand("%:t:r")
endfunction

autocmd BufNewFile * call NewFile()
```

You could also give something like [tSkeleton](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1160) a try, I've never tried myself but it seems to solve this problem for you.

Comment: Thanks! Where would I put all of this into my .vimrc file? Could you package it in a way that I could just use it "as is"? Should it be an :au straight after the templates one?

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at snipmate ([vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540), [github](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim)). It's a generic extension for boilerplate code, comes with a number of built-in recipes for Java (which you can browse [here](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim/blob/master/snippets/java.snippets) to get a feel for it), and is ideal for this kind of stuff.

With it, you can type in a keyword, hit tab, and have the keyword expanded into your boilerplate code. So you could type `stdclass->` and get what you're asking for.

The snippet can have vim expressions embedded (like `Filename()`); you can tab through important points in the expanded code, and it's useful for smaller snippets too (like getters & setters, try/catch/finally, toString, etc.)

It's easy to use, easy to customize, and in a boilerplate-heavy language like Java, it's a godsend.